# How to get image src (image name) inside a specific TR in multiple TR/TD table (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath

How can I get SRC of the image inside a TR with TD contains MainImage:

```
<tr>
<td>MainImage</td>
<td><img src="/img/mainimage.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image1</td>
<td><img src="/img/image1.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Image2</td>
<td><img src="/img/image2.png"></td>
</tr>
```

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
$imgname = $xpath->query('//td[contains(., "MainImage")]/following-sibling::*[1]')->item(0);
echo $imgname;
```

What I'm looking to extract is: mainimage.png or /img/mainimage.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expand the XPath expression.  This adds the `img` and also the attribute `@src` to the expression, this will give you a DOMAttr element, so you can then extract the value using `textContent`

```
$imgname = $xpath->query('//td[contains(., "MainImage")]/following-sibling::td[1]/img/@src')
    ->item(0)->textContent;
echo $imgname;
```

You could also change it to use `evaluate` and convert this node to a string directly in your XPath...

```
$imgname = $xpath->evaluate('string(//td[contains(., "MainImage")]/following-sibling::td[1]/img/@src)');
echo $imgname;
```

Comment: Thanks mate!
What if the img is in the same TD?

<td>MainImage <img src="/img/mainimage.png"></td>

Comment: You could instead say to find the `<td>` tag and then just look for the first `<img>` tag in the `<tr>` tag with `string(//td[contains(., "MainImage")]/../descendant::img/@src)`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Kindof new to php and not much familiar with it.